# Downloaded Font Not Showing Up in Browser

Tags: html, css, types, fonts, navigation

[image: Project Screenshot]

I need the text in the navigation bar and body to match the text at the top (the header). The text is called WindsorDemi.fog Cn. I downloaded it from fontzone.net and it seemed to work fine. In the body I have:

```
<p style="text-align:center;font-family:WindsorDemi.fog Cn">
<font size="4"> Welcome to daikininc.com! home of the world's greatest egg roll wrappers and noodles!
</font>
</p>
```

Just like I would do with any other font. I am using a dell latitude D630...is there a reason why the browser is not recognizing this font? I need the fonts to match. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the font name is correct:

```
font-family:WindsorDemi.fog Cn
```

That doesn't look right. It looks like you're using the file name instead. A simple guess could be:

```
font-family:Windsor
```

Comment: That made a lot of sense, unfortunately still didn't work though.

Comment: Definitely Windsor Bold. I don't have Word on the computer I'm using, just text edit and paint. It's not even showing up as a font in paint.

Comment: Then it could due to corrupted file, who knows, as long as you really are using the right font name. I installed a font once with a complete different name than the one I thought and I couldn't find it on photoshop. Then I saw it under a different name on the dropdown ist.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you set the style to:

```
style="text-align:center;font-family:WindsorDemi"
```

...It may work on your computer.

However, if you publish this page to the world wide web, only people who also have installed that font will see it as you do. For web pages you are stuck using generic font families, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography), or using web fonts like for example [google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) or the [many good options here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know web pages were restricted to certain fonts

Answer (score 1):

that font format is not supported by your browser. download the supported format from this link, make sure you check the browsers and operating systems supported before downloading http://font.downloadatoz.com/download,84557,windsordemi.html